# Special character on header - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use a data frame in which one of the headers is a lambda symbol (λ). On RStudio I can see the symbol correctly on my data frame but when I try to use this column as an axis on my ggplot it doesn't work. Is it possible to use it this way or I have to change the column header?

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example including all inputs, code and library statements. Read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag for guidance on how to ask a question.

Comment: Obviously, ggplot does not like your special character(s). In general, I recommend to avoid these (when possible). A way to convert the column headers into something ggplot is willing to accept is to wrap them into backticks, e.g. `column-header-special-char`. You can then work with ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=my_x, y="`lambda`")) or ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x=my_x, y=`lambda`)). Under the hood, the backticks convert the special character to a standard symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your column a normal name and specify the lambda like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  labs(x=expression(lambda))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>